# Tour: Why centered text, and no nbsp?

Tags: bug, design, new-users, tour, typography

Examples:

- https://meta.stackexchange.com/tour
  [image: List item]
- https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/tour

`div.col-full` has `text-align: center` instead of `text-align: left`, making them harder to read

From [Wikipedia -> Typographic alignment -> Centered:](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Typographic_alignment#Centered)

> Centered text is considered less readable for a body of text made up of multiple lines because the ragged starting edges make it difficult for the reader to track from one line to the next

More enjoyable, and still short read here: https://practicaltypography.com/centered-text.html

Relatedly: No `&nbsp;` before the last words in each `<p>` means that on softwarerecs, the words "recommendations" and "recommendation" stand alone. Not something I'd commend.